# On a saga context, how do I handle reducer errors?

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I have a saga:

```
function* mySaga() {
  try {
    yield put({type: 'ACTION_TYPE'})
  } catch (e) {
    handleError(e)
  }
}
```

If the reducer that handles `ACTION_TYPE` throws an error, the catch block won't run. At least not within my tests.

I have set up a Redux middleware to catch all errors and then dispatch an action that can update the store accordingly.

```
const errorHandlerMiddleware = store => next => action => {
  try {
    return next(action)
  } catch (err) {
    return next({
      type: 'START_ERROR_STATE',
      err: err
    })
  }  
}
```

But if I have another saga that puts two sequential actions:

```
function* anotherSaga() {
  try {
    yield put({type: 'ACTION_TYPE'})
    yield put({type: 'ANOTHER_ACTION_TYPE'})
  } catch (e) {
    handleError(e)
  }
}
```

Even if the reducer that handles the action of type `ACTION_TYPE` throws an error, `anotherSaga` will still dispatch `ANOTHER_ACTION_TYPE`. I don't want this to happen.

I have implemented a race:

```
function* raceSaga() {
  const { error} = yield race({
    main: call(anotherSaga),
    error: take('START_ERROR_STATE')
  })

  if (main) {
     yield put({type: 'SUCCESS_ACTION'})
  } else if (error) {
     yield put({type: 'ERROR_ACTION'})
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if it's the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with your redux setup. Citing redux documentation:

> The reducer is a pure function that takes the previous state and an action, and returns the next state

Which means that you can't throw errors inside reducers. It should take state, action object and return you next state. I suggest that you revisit redux documantation or some tutorial.

Comment: Fully agreed, which is why on error I dismiss all changes by the errored reducer and keep the state intact (I do this by implementing transactional reducers that save a clean copy and commit when finished). I throw type errors because some data is critical and I need to make sure other developers in the team are using them correctly.

Comment: What do you mean by: `dismiss all changes`? You should never modify a state inside a reducer but return a new one, that is the point of purity.

You should not have errors inside reducers. What you are saying indicates that your reducers are `not` pure functions which is violating redux assumptions.

Comment: You've said those things already. I've offered my explanation on how the error leaves the store intact.